# Finding threshold value

Tags: economics

first and foremost, I want to state that this is a homework question and I'm not sure if its against the rules, but I'm not looking for the answer, I'm just looking for the methodology to solve it as I can't find it anywhere else.

There was a post similar to this previously, but I had a hard time understanding it.

[how do i calculate the threshold value of the following problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237109/how-do-i-calculate-the-threshold-value-of-the-following-problem)

Is there anyone that can guide me through this question?

Comment: Could you point out which part you have difficulty understanding?

Comment: using the formula given in the comment, I got 
2000-((2000-100)x0.05)-(2000x0.01) = 1885. However, both answers given by the one asking the question and the person answering it did not match

Comment: Why do you have (2000-100)x0.05? The answer is not laying out that way though

Comment: The first occurs with probability 0.05 and would reduce the value of the asset to $100. Doesn't it mean that the expected loss would be 1900x0.05? Since the value dropped from 2000 to 100

Comment: So the question says the value is reduced to $100$, not reduce $100$

Answer (score 0):

Expected value from the asset Ev=$2000-1900\cdot 1({\text{event 1 occurs but 2 does not}})-2000\cdot 1(\text{event 2 occurs})
$

The point is if the asset (suppose a car) is totally destroyed, a reduction in value of the asset is irrelevant, I would not be able to sell the car and get anything out of it in any case.

I should be ready to pay $2000$-Ev

Comment: The loss in the first case is 1900. Quote:$\texttt{"...and would reduce the value of the asset}  \  \color{red}{to} \  \$100$"

Comment: Hi, thank you for the confirmation, however, the question that im faced with asked for the perspective of each party involved. How do I answer that?

Comment: I did not get that part, who are the parties involved? You and the insurance company?

Comment: Yes, just me and the insurance company

Comment: It should be the same number, as, the value of insurance is exactly what the insurance company are expected to pay on average.

Comment: If there is a chance of the value of the item increasing, will it affect the value of insurance at all?

Comment: If you want to insure for the extra returns (increased value) additionally, only then would it change things.